# What are disadvantages of Mapreduce 1 algorithms

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to know the disadvantages of Map Reduce 1 algorithms over MR2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here are two exciting and significant additions to the Hadoop framework:    

• HDFS  Federation: provides a name service that is both scalable and reliable. 

• YARN: Yet Another Resource Negotiator,it divides the two major functions        of the JobTracker(resource management and life cycle management) into separate          components.
```

A key issue with Hadoop 1.x was providing a Name Node that was highly-­‐available.    Not only does HDFS Federation provide an HA  name service,but it also allows distribution of workload since the Name Nodes can now scale horizontally.

YARN provides a logical separation of duties for negotiating and  executing jobs    across a Hadoop cluster.The end  result  of   YARN is a  new, more-­‐generic          resource management framework  that works with more  than just Map Reduce jobs.

```
Here are some of the articles 
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/02/mapreduce-2-0-in-hadoop-0-23/
http://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-apache-hadoop-yarn/

Hadoop 1.x is all about Map -reduce means you can run only map reduce but 
YARN is more general than MR and it should be possible to run other computing models like BSP besides MR. Prior to YARN, it required a separate cluster for MR, BSP and others. Now they they can coexist in a single cluster, which leads to higher usage of the cluster. Here are some of the applications ported to YARN.

In the current system, JobTracker views the cluster as composed of nodes (managed by individual TaskTrackers) with distinct map slots and reduce slots, which are not fungible.  Utilization issues occur because maps slots might be ‘full’ while reduce slots are empty (and vice-versa).  Fixing this was necessary to ensure the entire system could be used to its maximum capacity for high utilization..

Also, it makes it possible to run different versions of Hadoop in the same cluster which is not possible with legacy MR, which makes is easy from a maintenance point.
```

Answer (score 0):

What I feel like is the main difficulty of MR1 is

**Difficult to do Algorithms that require global, sharing states.**